# Should scrolling be disabled when there are no items to scroll to?

Tags: ios, scrolling

Assume a horizontal scrollview is being populated with 2 views, leaving 80% of the scroller empty.

Should scrolling be disabled?
Allowing the user to scroll makes the 2 views move without a purpose.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. An accidental click on your scroll bar (or other scroll trigger) will leave your user staring a blank screen.

Comment: Though you may want to show an inactive scroll bar so that the layout doesn't jump unpleasantly when scrolling does become necessary.

Comment: iOS generally uses these invisible scroll bars anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would let it scroll, but with some kind of bouncing like iOS does. That is a nice way to inform that you have reached the end of the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Not disabling the scrollbar tells the user "scroll there might be more" even if there is nothing more. I have user tested a product recently where the scrollbar appears enabled and people did click the scrollbar even when the page wasn't filled with the items completely. You could also hide the scrollbar to make it more obvious that there is nothing more.